# Cross-Origin in JHipster's microservices

Tags: spring-security, jhipster, microservices

I've created Microservices using Jhipster. The security mechanism is "UAA". the problem is a Cross-origin issue prevents loging in and communicating with uaa server.

The below message I got from chrome browser:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.136:9999/login. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.136:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Where Gateway is on port 8080 and UAA is on port 9999.

How to resolve Cross-Origin issue in Microservices Architecture?

Could you help, please..

Answer (score 2):

first...the UAA does NOT define a /login path...the login happens via OAuth 2.0 password grant in the gateway.

The other point is, that you are reaching the UAA directly. This is not the Netflix way, as you point to a real host + port, instead of getting this info from zuul. As for zuul, you know the name of your uaa service (its "uaa"), and zuul builds paths like "host/serviceNameInUpperCase/path for service"

so try http://192.168.1.136:8080/uaa/api/... instead of http://192.168.1.136:9999/api/...

I believe, this will also fix your CORS issue

Comment: I searched for "/login" in source code and I couldn't find it but if I open it from browser I got page asking me for Username and password .

 The client I'm using default Jhipster's Angular 2. So, No modification happened yet!

The browser can get the token via http://192/168.1.136/uaa/oauth/token but cannot proceed in other requests because cross-origin issue

Comment: By  the way, "/login" is builtin in Spring Security

Comment: only if you activate it using WebSecurity. As we use ResourceServerSecurity, this path is not defined (try it).The CORS issue can only happen if your browser tries to resolve URL from another host. AFAIK this cannot happen with default JHipster generated code, if you didn't changed that. In our case, the angular application only makes url to itself, since we know the JHipster gateway is a zuul proxy. And since we use Oauth 2.0 password grant instead of authorization code grant, there even is no redirect to /login